# How to check start and end row in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

My XLSX structure is as below:

[image]

I want to add a validation to check if the data starts at A6 and ends at A9 after skipping first 5 rows. so below is where I started:

```
    class structureError(Exception):
                """Thrown when data doesn't start at A6 and end at A9
                Attributes:message -- explanation of the error
                """
                def __init__(self, message="Structural issue in this file. Data 
    should start from row A6 and ends at A9"):
                        self.message = message
                        super().__init__(self.message)
    df_empty = pd.read_excel(readxldata, skiprows=5, sheet_name=sheetname)
    ##Grab the row and check if it starts from A6 and ends at A9
       raise structureError()
```

How to validate the start and end row in a dataframe?

Comment: What you try to validate is neither a CSV file nor a DataFrame but seems to be a spreadsheet file.

Comment: Yup. Excel and CSV are not synonymous. Consider using `openpyxl` to determine the boundaries of data on the sheet.

Comment: @mozway I added a dummy snip to present my question. My file is actually xlsx one